# Why does invitations sent from Apple software to users with GMail- or Hotmail-based Apple ID:s get mangled?

Tags: apple-id, calendar, gmail, ical, hotmail

Problem: I have two friends that regularly send me calendar invitations. When these invitations arrive, the from-address is changed to *noreply@email.apple.com*. Confirming these invitations doesn't work, probably because the confirmation is sent to noreply@email.apple.com rather than my friends' addresses.

Premises:

- I have a GMail-address *abc@gmail.com*
- I have an Apple-ID based on a GMail-address. The main address for my Apple-ID is *abc+apple.com@gmail.com* but *abc@gmail.com* is also registered with the same Apple-ID.
- My friends use iOS-devices, one with a GMail-address *friend1@gmail.com*, one with a Hotmail-address, *friend2@hotmail.com*.

When my friends use either the built in iOS or MacOS calender and invite abc@gmail.com I receive an invitation with *noreply@email.apple.com* as sender sent to *abc+apple.com@gmail.com*. It **should** be *friend1@gmail.com* or *friend2@hotmail.com* as sender and *abc@gmail.com* as receiver.

Comment: Is the solution already the answer?

Comment: @nohillside Yes.

Comment: Please post it as an answer below then and upvote/accept it.

Comment: @nohillside I can't do that until a couple of days has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using https://apps.apple.com/app/google-calendar-get-organised/id909319292 on iOS or https://calendar.google.com/ (or the corresponding calender for Hotmail) for desktop works better. I haven't done extensive experimenting but so far it has worked. Comments describing your experience are very welcome.